# А на самом деле можно выделять и частицу, и вводное слово "небось"?

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова, части-речи

Грамота делит значения этого слова именно [так](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_462). Не увидел в описании вводного слова и частицы принципиальной разницы. А если вводным оно не бывает, то тогда его не надо обособлять же никогда. Правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**На "Грамоте"** по поводу [небось](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C) не много информации.

**Вопрос** № 240275
*Небось картошку все мы уважаем...* Нужна ли запятая после *небось*? Спасибо за своевременный ответ.
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Запятая не нужна.

**Вопрос** № 204795
Является ли слово *небось* вводным и выделяется ли запятыми?
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Слово *небось* может быть вводным в вопросительных предложениях в значении «вероятно, не правда ли». В этом случае *небось* выделяется запятыми.

**У Розенталя** в примечании к пункту 8 ([§ 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)) говорится, что *небось* не является вводным словом и не выделяется запятыми.

> Пунктуационное выделение этих слов в некоторых текстах объясняется разными причинами: в одних случаях сказывается то обстоятельство, что некоторые из приведенных слов относятся к так называемым модальным частицам, близким к модальным (вводным) словам; в других — играют роль смысловые оттенки, присущие отдельным словам и допускающие их выделение запятыми; наконец, возможно влияние прежних правил или индивидуальной авторской пунктуации. Ср.: <...>
> ***Небось** струсил, паренёк?; Замёрзли **небось**?; Все они небось виноваты.
> **Небось,** на нас не сунутся* (П.); *Одним не птица мельница, что, как ни машет крыльями, **небось,** не полетит* (Н.); *Ну а жена твоя? **Небось,** красавица* (Ч.).

Интересную информацию дает **редакторское бюро** «По правилам».
[Небось](https://popravilam.com/blog/144-nebos.html)
«Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений» пишет про эту частицу:

> **1.** Употребляется в функции вводного в модальном значении «**неуверенность**, предположение» (обычно в вопросительном предложении): *Все того же Шекспира, небось, заставляет себе переводить?* (Н. Лесков); *Небось, покамест долетишь, так об стенки головой изобьешься?* (А. Куприн); *Дворников-то, небось, заметили, проходя* (Ф. Достоевский).
> **2.** Невводное, употребляется в функции модальной частицы со значением «утверждение, **уверенность**»: *Небось видел в лесу — есть лист желтый и есть лист красный* (К. Паустовский); *Небось не маленький.*
> Различить эти случаи зачастую представляется затруднительным. Решение об обособлении принимает автор текста.

Оно же рекомендует запомнить не жесткие ориентиры:
• вопросительное предложение, неуверенность — пишем с запятой (аналог — «наверное»):
*Небось, трудно запомнить все правила?*;
• повествовательное предложение, уверенность — не ставим запятую (аналог — «наверняка»): *Небось они-то знают, как писать*.

В итоге — на самом деле похоже, что все делают выбор в зависимости от своего *собственного восприятия* текста (но на то ты, если разобраться, и *автор*).

Вот пример из классики (А. П. Чехов. Дядя Ваня): в [одних](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5d-_DwAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PR135&lpg=RA1-PR135&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8?%20%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%92.%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB.&source=bl&ots=VwSzcxyQlq&sig=ACfU3U2wv1ijrPQ8vWcrAibMlez4adKN-g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj524-y58L9AhW8BxAIHZQ9BPI4ChDoAXoECBMQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%3F%20%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%92.%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB.&f=false) изданиях есть запятые, в [других](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HejHAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8?%20%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%92.%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81,%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB.&source=bl&ots=_D4s-gxiiV&sig=ACfU3U22yoaC0Q7VjgsMCcN4R9AP83U57g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj524-y58L9AhW8BxAIHZQ9BPI4ChDoAXoECBoQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%3F%20%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%92.%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB.&f=false) — нет:
Соня. *И прекрасно. Это такая редкость, что вы у нас ночуете. Вы, **небось,** не обедали?*
Астров. *Нет-с, не обедал.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, Рим! Очень интересно)

Comment: И тебе, Артём, — слова добрые. Жаль, правда, что вопрос никому, кроме меня, не показался интересным. Спорная ведь тема, *пользительная*.